# How to add a character in every end of all lines with notepad++

Tags: replace, character, line, notepad++

Basicaly title says it all, mine file looks like this:

```
"edit Product",""Home > Opto-electronics > LED > Standard LED, Multicolour"","2226",""KINGBRIGHT LED, 3MM, HE-RED/GRN L-93WEGW"",""SC07621"","197
"edit Product",""Home > Resistors > Fixed"","2228",""VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 10K0 CRCW040210K0JNEAIF"",""RE06211"","50
"edit Product",""Home > Resistors > Fixed"","2229",""VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 3R90 CRCW04023R90JNEAIF"",""RE06212"","-1
"edit Product",""Home > Resistors > Fixed"","2230",""VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 2R70 CRCW04022R70JNEAIF"",""RE06220"","25
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
"edit Product",""Home > Opto-electronics > LED > Standard LED, Multicolour"","2226",""KINGBRIGHT LED, 3MM, HE-RED/GRN L-93WEGW"",""SC07621"","197
"edit Product",""Home > Resistors > Fixed"","2228",""VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 10K0 CRCW040210K0JNEAIF"",""RE06211"","50**"**
"edit Product",""Home > Resistors > Fixed"","2229",""VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 3R90 CRCW04023R90JNEAIF"",""RE06212"","-1**"**
"edit Product",""Home > Resistors > Fixed"","2230",""VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 2R70 CRCW04022R70JNEAIF"",""RE06220"","25**"**
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press `ctrl + h` check enter as **Find what** `\n`, set **Replace with** as `"\n` and set the **Search Mode** as `Extended`.

That should work.

Comment: it adds new line with character " after every line

Comment: Try to use `\r\n` instad of `\n`.